# How can I make Mocha test compile Ruby-ish Unicode string?

Tags: node.js, ruby, unicode, emoji, ruby-mocha

I'm invoking Telegram Bot API from a `Node.js` application. I need to send some Unicode characters to the API, that only accepts Ruby format (`\u{1F680}` outputs  ). I store all Unicode characters in this format in a file that is required by the one actually sending the message to the API.

Node.js is ok with this, it's working fine. However, when I run Mocha tests on the same code, it results in an `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error, it doesn't like the Ruby Unicode format. The test itself isn't even using this Unicode character, the compilation is what fails.

```
emojis.rocket = '\u{1F680}';
                ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/file/values_es.js:1:76)
  // more error lines... 
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

If I change it to the JavaScript Unicode format (`\u1F680`), Mocha and Node.js are OK with it, but the API doesn't get it as the appropriate character.

I've tried the following:

- Store in JavaScript format `\u1F680` and then adding the `{}` in runtime, but it outputs a different character (Ὠ0), corresponding to the first four HEX values (`\u1F68`) and the extra `0`.
- Store in JavaScript format `\u1F680` and adding encode Ruby function `code.encode('UTF-8')` just in case Telegram Bot API executes Ruby code. Not working either, it prints `\u1F680.encode('UTF-8')`.

Is there any way in which I can make Mocha accept Ruby-ish (`\u{1F680}`) format?

Answer (score 0):

Use the RegExp constructor to pass it through the mocha test:

```
RegExp('\u{1F680}')
```

then use `exec` and `toString` to convert it to a string:

```
RegExp('\u{1F680}').exec('\u{1F680}').toString()
```

**References**

- [ES2015 unicode regex transform · Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-unicode-regex/)
- [What every JavaScript developer should know about Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)
- [String.fromCodePoint() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)